# Change the values in a column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this csv

```
name,age,count
will,12,2
joe,22,4
tim,34,10
```

I want to reset all the values in the table count to 0

```
name,age,count
will,12,0
joe,22,0
tim,34,0
```

To change the values

```
file = pd.read_csv("./users.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
df["count"].replace({ to_replace: value }, inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to do it without mentioning `to_replace` and setting the value directly?

Comment: without to replace which one going to be replaced ?

Comment: ```df['count'] = 0```?

Comment: @BENY I want to replace all the values using the column `count`. That's it

Answer (score 1):

In your case just assign back

```
df["count"] = 0
```